# How to have multiple markers on google map in rails application somewhat similar to nestigator.com?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am having problem with my app. I am unable to fetch longitudes and latitudes from database saved through geocode and i want to make a map having all markers from database data on a single map.
    I need to ask how to have multiple markers on google map containing all the markers for locations in 10 miles radius in rails application somewhat similar to nestigator.com?
    Plz help me out as i have tried many things but nothing succeeding.
    Here is the code for my view file.

```
<!--show.html.erb-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=Init&sensor=false"></script>    <!-- Google Maps API -->
    <script>

    enter code here


    function Init()
    {
    var map;    // Google map object

        // Create a Google coordinate object for where to initially center the map
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( <%= @location.latitude %>,<%= @location.longitude %> );   // Washington, DC

        // Map options for how to display the Google map
        var mapOptions = { zoom: 14, center: latlng  };

        // Show the Google map in the div with the attribute id 'map-canvas'.
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map:map,
            draggable: true,
            position: latlng,
            title: '<%= @location.address %>',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          });
        marker.setMap(map);

    }

    // Update the Google map for the user's inputted address
    function UpdateMap( )
    {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();    // instantiate a geocoder object

        // Get the user's inputted address
        var address = document.getElementById( "address" ).value;

        // Make asynchronous call to Google geocoding API
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
            var addr_type = results[0].types[0];    // type of address inputted that was geocoded
            if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) 
                ShowLocation( results[0].geometry.location, address, addr_type );
            else     
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);        
        });
    }
    // Show the location (address) on the map.
    function ShowLocation( latlng, address, addr_type )
    {
        // Center the map at the specified location
        map.setCenter( latlng );

        // Set the zoom level according to the address level of detail the user specified
        var zoom = 12;
        switch ( addr_type )
        {
        case "administrative_area_level_1"  : zoom = 6; break;      // user specified a state
        case "locality"                     : zoom = 10; break;     // user specified a city/town
        case "street_address"               : zoom = 16; break;     // user specified a street address
        }
        map.setZoom( zoom );

        // Place a Google Marker at the same location as the map center 
        // When you hover over the marker, it will display the title
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker( { 
            position: latlng,     
            map: map,      
            title: address
        });

        // Create an InfoWindow for the marker
        var contentString = "" + address + "";  // HTML text to display in the InfoWindow
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow( { content: contentString } );

        // Set event to display the InfoWindow anchored to the marker when the marker is clicked.
        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() { infowindow.open( map, marker ); });
    }

    // Call the method 'Init()' to display the google map when the web page is displayed ( load event )
    google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', Init );


    </script>
    <style>
    /* style settings for Google map */
    #map-canvas
    {
        width : 600px;     /* map width */
        height: 400px;  /* map height */
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body> 
<br>
    <!-- Dislay Google map here -->
    <br/>
   <h5><b>Search:</b></h5>
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" id="address" class="form-control" style="width:480px;"/>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button onclick="UpdateMap()" class="btn btn-primary">Locate</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <h3><%= @location.address %></h3><h6 id="notice"><%= notice %></h6>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
<div id='map-canvas'></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
<h3>Nearby locations</h3>
<ul>
<% for location in @location.nearbys(10) %>
  <li><%= link_to location.address, location %> (<%= location.distance.round(2) %> miles)</li>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_location_path(@location) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', locations_path %>
</ul>
</div>
<br>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood right, u will enter a location coordinate and see places on map whic is in distance that known .

So firstly u need to write a fuction that calculates distance and if this function if distance is what u want then return result1 for function, then u will use this function in one loop that u get data from your database  control with if statement if result one then firsly make your marker as array then in for loop create your markers

```
function calcCrow(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) 
{
  var R = 6371; // km
  var dLat = toRad(lat2-lat1);
  var dLon = toRad(lon2-lon1);
  var lat1 = toRad(lat1);
  var lat2 = toRad(lat2);

  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c;
  return d;
}

// Converts numeric degrees to radians
function toRad(Value) 
{
    return Value * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

this is one example of calculation .
in for loop u can control with if statement like

```
 if(caLCROW<2000){create your markers}
```